# Why Vs Code doesn't see the new version of GO?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I am a newby in coding, I learn Go as my first programming language. I updated Go for the new version (1.18) (as described here: https://go.dev/doc/install) and VS Code as well (1.66.0) So my terminal sees the new version of go, and actually VS Code shows it also correctly at the bottom of the window. (I use Manjaro Linux, zsh)

But when I declare an interface with type of any it shows something went wrong:

type Mixer interface {
Mix(outPtr any, ingredients ...any) error
}
undeclared name: any (requires version go1.18 or later)compiler

Can someone help me please what did I wrong?

Comment: Have you made sure the go extension is up to date?

Comment: I have deleted the old version of Go. When I check in the terminal it shows only the new version.  I don't know where else should I check it .

Comment: Did you run "Go: Update/Install Tools"? If not, please run it so tools are recompiled with go1.18.

The Go extension should've prompt about need for updating tools. Didn't it show a notification popup?